# Configure Postfix to allow incoming mails only from one (defined) mail-id

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, postfix-mta, email-validation, piping

I have set-up Postfix with Spamassassin on Ubuntu 12.04.5. Fundamental usage of Postfix is to (pipe) trigger a PHP file. Till here I've arrived successfully.

Now, to avoid unneccessary load on the server, and also to avoid unwanted mails triggering my PHP script, I want to configure Postfix to allow mails only from my@domain.com and reject everything else.

How to achieve this absolute lock-down on mail server unless mail comes from my@domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following `smtpd_sender_restrictions` to your `main.cf` to receive mails only from `my@domain.com`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/mine_only

#/etc/postfix/mine_only
/^my@domain.com$/   OK
/^/                 REJECT
```